# If a recovery key is present in Microsoft account, does that mean that the Device Encryption was turned on?

Tags: windows, windows-11, disk-encryption

I lost a Windows 11 Home laptop. I was logging in with my Microsoft account. I don't know if the Device Encryption was on. I can see that there is a recovery key in my account for this computer.

Does that mean that the Device Encryption was on or not necessarily?

Comment: It means Device Encryption is currently turned on, which is the default for new Windows 10 or Windows 11 Home machines.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. If the encryption was disabled, the online account will not always reflect these changes.

But of course the chances are high that encryption was enabled.
It's hard to say, but good luck. It's never fun to lose a PC.

Comment: What I meant is if the device did not satisfy MS requirements for device encryption, it would not turn on automatically. But if there are recovery keys, does that mean that the encryption was on at least at some point?